# How to center the text mesh in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am currently building a tool with `Three.js`.
I would like to put **dot**s with corresponding **number**s (dot count).
Below code is how I implemented. *(Please teach me if there are better ways)*

To align two meshes, I relocated them so that the text (number) can be inside the center of the dot. **However, the problem is that the position of the text is based on meshes left side, not the center.** So that if the numbers gain more digits, they wouldn't align as I expected.

Is there a better way to align text mesh so that they can be on the center of the circle?

```
var totalDotCount = 0;
function addDotMeshToGroup(x, y) { // x,y coordinate
  ...
  // Dot
  var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(0.4, 32);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFF00});
  var dotMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

  // Number Text
  var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry(totalDotCount.toString(10), textParm);
  var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, material);

  // Relocation
  dotMesh.position.set(x, y, 0);
  textMesh.position.set(x - 0.2, y - 0.2, 0);

  totalDotCount += 1;
  ...
}
```

Picture 01 [Expected]

[image]

Picture 02 [Unexpected]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case, modelling the circle and numbers as 3d-objects is probably a bit overkill. Instead, you can create a simple plane and add the circle and number to it using a texture. Textures can be created on the fly using a canvas-element, something like this:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = canvas.height = 256;

// draw/fill the circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(128, 128, 128, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.fill();

// draw the number
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.font = '64px sans-serif';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
ctx.fillText('12', 128, 128);

// create mesh with texture
const mesh = new Mesh(
  new PlaneGeometry(1,1),
  new MeshBasicMaterial({transparent: true, map: new CanvasTexture(canvas)})
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This actually is a much better way for my case.